# How to script a database in LocalDB?

Tags: visual-studio, localdb

I've created a database in LocalDB using Visual Studio 2017/Community Edition. I don't see any menu where I can script the whole database so that I can recreate it in another machine. I uninstalled SSMS from this machine because there was not much space in this computer.

Comment: You can connect to it using Sql Server Management Studio

Comment: I uninstalled SSMS from this machine because there was not much space in this computer. I made a choice of keeping only visual studio because it has `localdb`.

Comment: Well, if you locate the file you can move it to a different PC with the same Sql Server Version and use the SSMS from there. If this is one time job.....